# Using ::after selector for a button hover effect not visible

Tags: css

I want to create an effect such that when mouse hovered on the button it would have larger button quickly appear then disappear. I would expect .btn::after would be visible immediately but right now it is invisible. My goal right now is just to make .btn::after visible.

html

```
 <header class="header">
   <div class="header__logo-box">
     <img src="https://dtgxwmigmg3gc.cloudfront.net/imagery/assets/derivations/icon/256/256/true/eyJpZCI6ImE4OWEzMGU2YTg5NTViYjcxZWY1OTJiNDlkYjZjMTRhLmpwZyIsInN0b3JhZ2UiOiJwdWJsaWNfc3RvcmUifQ?signature=8735e0713b1bd34828e75056d2c51efc7ffc62c0167dcb80e7d66fe8550b9bc6" alt="Logo" class="header__logo">
   </div>

   <div class="header__text-box">
     <h1 class="heading-primary">
       <span class="heading-primary--main">Outdoors</span>
       <span class="heading-primary--sub">is where life happens</span>
     </h1>

     <a href="#section-tours" class="btn btn--white btn--animated">Discover our tours</a>
   </div>
</header>
```

CSS relevant to .btn:

```
.btn
{
  padding: 10px 30px;  
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn--white
{
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* this has no effect */
.btn::after
{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  transition: all .4s;
}

/* this has no effect */
.btn:hover::after
{
  transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ybo6xgsf/3/

Possibly error is in other parts of CSS so please have a look at the jsfiddle link.

Comment: do u want zoom effect on hover for btn?

Comment: effect on .btn:hover::after

Comment: What if you put the hover on `.btn::after`, like this? `.btn::after:hover`

Comment: @JustinFeakes no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
background: white;
z-index: -1;
```

to your `.btn::after`, I see the effect.

```css
.header
{
  background-image: url(https://images2.minutemediacdn.com/image/upload/c_crop,h_2450,w_4368,x_0,y_165/f_auto,q_auto,w_1100/v1562080363/shape/mentalfloss/29942-gettyimages-155302141.jpg);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  height: 80vh;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 70%);
  position: relative;
}

.header::after
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #34c9eb, #0c4f5e);
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: -1;
}

.header__logo-box
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;  
  width: 80px;
}

.header__logo
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header__text-box
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.heading-primary--main
{
  display: block;
}

.heading-primary--sub
{
  display: block;  
}

.btn
{
  padding: 10px 30px;  
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn--white
{
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* this has no effect */
.btn::after
{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  transition: all .4s;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* this has no effect */
.btn:hover::after
{
  transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
 <div class="header__logo-box">
   <img src="https://dtgxwmigmg3gc.cloudfront.net/imagery/assets/derivations/icon/256/256/true/eyJpZCI6ImE4OWEzMGU2YTg5NTViYjcxZWY1OTJiNDlkYjZjMTRhLmpwZyIsInN0b3JhZ2UiOiJwdWJsaWNfc3RvcmUifQ?signature=8735e0713b1bd34828e75056d2c51efc7ffc62c0167dcb80e7d66fe8550b9bc6" alt="Logo" class="header__logo">
 </div>

 <div class="header__text-box">
   <h1 class="heading-primary">
     <span class="heading-primary--main">Outdoors</span>
     <span class="heading-primary--sub">is where life happens</span>
   </h1>

   <a href="#section-tours" class="btn btn--white btn--animated">Discover our tours</a>
 </div>
</header>
```